# Openseadragon: prevent canvas click if overlay is clicked

Tags: javascript, click, openseadragon

How can I prevent canvas click when overlay is clicked? I binded action for overlay but canvas action is fired first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MouseTracker. Here's an example:

http://codepen.io/iangilman/pen/mEkKaY

Here's the key bit of code:

```
var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
    ...,
    overlays: [
        {
            id: 'overlay1',
            ...
        }
    ]
});

new OpenSeadragon.MouseTracker({
    element: 'overlay1'
});
```